# How Do I Write An If Statement in PowerPivot

Tags: powerpivot

All,

Just started working with PowerPivot. How do I write a if statement?

I want to see if one value is less than another. If it is, then 0 else 1

```
=IF(Agent_Daily_Intradiem_TinT[Task Name Count]<Agent_Daily_Intradiem_TinT[Total Task Count]) , 0, 1)
```

Comment: Sorry. the whole formula did not paste. =IF(Agent_Daily_Intradiem_TinT[Task Name Count])<(Agent_Daily_Intradiem_TinT[Total Task Count]) then 0, 1)

Answer (score 0):

@Derlin's edit was almost perfect except for an extra paren. This is correct.

```
=IF(Agent_Daily_Intradiem_TinT[Task Name Count]<Agent_Daily_Intradiem_TinT[Total Task Count] , 0, 1)
```

If you put this as a calculated column it should work. If it is a measure it will fail I believe. Did you want a calculated column?

Comment: Excellent! Thanks to both for the quick response!